# How to position a div at the bottom of the page correctly?

Tags: css

I have divs like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

now I use this style for my container and footer:

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
div.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
div.footer {
  width:100%;
  height: 40px;
  positioin: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

So, the footer stays at the bottom relative to the page, it is good, but I found out two problems:

1. if the body div's content is too long, it will overlap the footer!
2. I want the background color of the footer to span over the whole browser view port, but currently it is just as wide as its the container div.

Any idea of how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

My best tip is to use [A CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/), works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

place the footer div out of the container and give marin-top:-(height:px)px;.

```
<div class="footer"></div>

html, body {
  height:100%;
}
div.container {
  min-height: 100%;
}
div.footer {
  width:100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top:-40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `bottom: -40px;`.

The `bottom` property positions your element so that the *bottom* of your element is offset by the bottom of the containing element by this amount.  So if you had `bottom: 0;` as in your example, the bottom of your element is aligned with the bottom of its containing element, hence it will overlap it.

> I want the background color of the footer to span over the whole browser view port, but currently it is just as wide as its the container div.

This is because the `width: 100%;` is defined relative to the containing block of the element, which is the div.container (which is set to `position: relative`).  You would have to take it out of this container, or not define the container as `position: relative;` to fix this.